# Remove corrupt torrents

Tags: bash, debian

I don't remember where I found it, but I have a script that will remove torrents from transmission once they have completed seeding.

I want to add a section that also removes corrupt torrents. Torrents that are corrupt will have the following line:

**Error: No data found! Ensure your drives are connected or use "Set Location". To re-download, remove the torrent and re-add it.**

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

#transmission-remote --auth=user:pass --torrent 1 --info
#transmission-remote --auth=user:pass --list

TRUSER='user'
TRPASS='pass'
TORRENTLIST=`transmission-remote --auth=$TRUSER:$TRPASS --list | sed -e '1d;$d;s/^ *//' | cut --only-delimited --delimiter=' ' --fields=1`


for TORRENTID in $TORRENTLIST
do
echo "* * * * * Operations on torrent ID $TORRENTID starting. * * * * *"
DL_COMPLETED=`transmission-remote --auth=$TRUSER:$TRPASS --torrent $TORRENTID --info | grep "State: Finished"`
if [ "$DL_COMPLETED" != "" ]; then
echo "Torrent #$TORRENTID is completed."
echo "Removing torrent from list."
transmission-remote --auth=$TRUSER:$TRPASS --torrent $TORRENTID --remove-and-delete
else
echo "Torrent #$TORRENTID is not completed. Ignoring."
fi
echo "* * * * * Operations on torrent ID $TORRENTID completed. * * * * *"
done


for TORRENTID in $TORRENTLIST
do
echo "* * * * * Operations on torrent ID $TORRENTID starting. * * * * *"
DL_STOPPED='transmission-remote --auth=$TRUSER:$TRPASS --torrent $TORRENTID --info | grep -o "Error: No data found"'
if [ "$DL_STOPPED" = !"" ]; then
echo "Torrent #$TORRENTID is corrupted."
echo "Removing torrent from list."
transmission-remote --auth=$TRUSER:$TRPASS --torrent $TORRENTID --remove-and-delete
else
echo "Torrent #$TORRENTID is not corrupted. Ignoring."
fi
echo "* * * * * Operations on torrent ID $TORRENTID completed. * * * * *"
done
```

I thought that adding the '-o' after grep would solve my problem, but instead this deletes all torrents that aren't corrupted.

How can I have this script remove completed seeding and corrupt torrents?

This is my first time posting, so I hope I did this right.

Eddie

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using single quotes instead of back quotes.

Change the line:

```
DL_STOPPED='transmission-remote --auth=$TRUSER:$TRPASS --torrent $TORRENTID --info | grep -o "Error: No data found"'
```

to:

```
DL_STOPPED=`transmission-remote --auth=$TRUSER:$TRPASS --torrent $TORRENTID --info | grep -o "Error: No data found"`
```

Single quotes denote a string in bash whereas backquotes execute the string in a subshell. In anycase, I think its better to use then `$( ...)` since this notation allows for nesting.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html for a good description

**In addition**, you should change the `if` from :

```
if [ "$DL_STOPPED" = !"" ]; then
```

to:

```
if [ "$DL_STOPPED" != "" ]; then
```

Comment: Hi bronsted,

Thanks for the reply, I think you have me in the right direction.

So, not instead of all torrents saying corrupted, they are all saying not corrupted.

    Torrent #16 is not corrupted. Ignoring.
    Torrent #18 is not corrupted. Ignoring.
    Torrent #19* is not corrupted. Ignoring.

But, I did notice that the one that is corrupted has an asterisk behind the number. Torrent 19 is the one that should be corrupted.